# How to store a dynamically added content to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am having a few trouble storing my content into the database. The table/rows are dynamically generated using jquery! but when i click the submit button, just a row of numbers is stored in my database table even when i store text values. Here is my jquery code:

```
function addRow(tableID) { 
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "checkbox";
element1.name="chkbox[]";
cell1.appendChild(element1);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='Obstacle'>";
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
cell3.innerHTML = "<select name='Likelihood'> <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";

var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
cell4.innerHTML = "<select name='Severity'> <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";

var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell5.innerHTML = "<select name='Priority'> <option value='1'>Low</option> <option value='2'>Medium</option><option value='3'>High</option>/>";
}
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="compTable">
<form action="" method="post">  

<TABLE width="425" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="4"></th>
<th width="100">Obstacle</th>
<th width="50">Likelihood</th>
<th width="50">Severity</th>
<th width="50">Priotity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="dataTable">
</tbody>
</TABLE>
<INPUT type="submit" value="Save" name="submit" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Obstacle" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Obstacle" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
</form>
</div>
```

and finally my php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user = $_SESSION['user']['FullName'];
$obstacleDec = isset($_POST["Obstacle"][$key]);
$likelihoodScale = isset($_POST["Likelihood"][$key]);
$severityScale = isset($_POST["Severity"][$key]);
$priorityScale = isset($_POST["Priority"]);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
$sql = "INSERT INTO obstacles (ObstacleID, ObstacleDescription, Priority, Uncertainty, Severity, UserName, ComplianceID, Accepted)
VALUES (:ID, :obstacleDec, :priorityScale, :likelihoodScale, :severityScale, :aUser, :compID, :accepted)";

try{
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result= $stmt->execute(array(':ID'=>'', ':obstacleDec'=>$obstacleDec,':likelihoodScale'=>$likelihoodScale, ':severityScale'=>$severityScale,':priorityScale'=>$priorityScale, ':aUser'=>$user, ':compID'=>'', ':accepted'=>'' ));
}
catch(PDOException $ex){ 
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

header("Location: obstacles.php"); 
die("Redirecting to obstacles.php");
if(!$sql){
die("error inserting values");
}
else{
die("successfully inserted the values");
}
}
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: *"just a row of figures"* what do you mean by that?

Comment: i meant just numbers are stored instead of the original content. I checked my table attributes but that was not the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you only get the last filled data from each different fields that happens because your fields name is not a array, change the names adding on end **[]**

Like that:

```
<input type='text' name='Obstacle[]'>
```

And the same for the others fields.
Also you can optimize your php code a little bit more like that bellow.
I don't have your code but you can use var_dump($_POST) to check and correct.

**code updated**

```
<?php
//simulating data from form
$_POST = array(
               'Obstacle' => array('ob1', 'ob2', 'ob3'),
               'Likelihood' => array('l1', 'l2', 'l3'),
               'Severity' => array('s1', 's2', 's3'),
               'Priority' => array('p1', 'p2', 'p3'),
               );
$user = 1;

//the code
 $sql = "INSERT INTO obstacles (ObstacleDescription, Priority, Uncertainty, Severity, UserName, ComplianceID, Accepted)
    VALUES (:ID, :obstacleDec, :priorityScale, :likelihoodScale, :severityScale, :aUser, :compID, :accepted)";
    // $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

    for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['Obstacle']); $i++) {
        $values = array(':obstacleDec'=>$_POST['Obstacle'][$i],':likelihoodScale'=>$_POST['Likelihood'][$i], ':severityScale'=>$_POST['Severity'][$i],':priorityScale'=>$_POST['Priority'][$i], ':aUser'=>$user, ':compID'=>'', ':accepted'=>'' );
        // var_dump($values);
        try{
            $result= $stmt->execute($values);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }

    header("Location: obstacles.php");
    die("Redirecting to obstacles.php");
    //the ifs you have here are not necessary, your code will never get here
```

Comment: thanks for the help Lucas! but i now get some errors for  Undefined variable: key. do i solve these by just removing the [key]?? and what is its primary purpose?? really appreciate the help

Comment: Hey saint, the $key on this foreach will be the name of the fields: `Obstacle, Likelihood, etc` the value will be the value of then.

Comment: Now I change the code with a better simulating, maybe will help you more :)

Comment: sorry for the questions but im still quite new to php. the $_POST array, i actually want to store the contents from each column that was entered by a user.. so under obstacles, it will be text values and under the remaining columns it will be numbers from the dropdown boxes.

Comment: Yes, thats it, the `$_POST = array...` I put just simulating a form `POST`, you can use that to check if the data has been saved on database and correct/improve the code for your needs, if thats past you comment the `$_POST = array` and the `$user=1;` and test with your own form. You can found useful adding `var_dump($_POST);` on beginning of the php file to check how the data came from the form.